# Emulate waiting for input() in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

I am trying to recreate a command-line application into a desktop one using Tkinter. I cannot seem to figure out how to recreate the **input()** function - waiting for input and pressing Enter to confirm. Has anyone had a similar issue?

I have looked into **button_pressed** in Tkinter. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a tkinter `Text` widget.  Pressing "enter" should fire the "default" button, so you'll need a handler for that button, where you fetch the result.  If this is something separate from your regular GUI, perhaps you want tkinter's `simpledialog.askstring`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html

Comment: The `simpledialog.askstring` was perfect. Thanks